# vpnc networkmanager-vpnc-gnome cannot install in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, vpn, vpnc

I try to use this command `sudo apt install vpnc networkmanager-vpnc-gnome` to install in Ubuntu20.04, but it shows that **E: Unable to locate package networkmanager-vpnc-gnome**.
How to solved it? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Step 1： `sudo apt-get update -y`

Step 2:  `sudo apt-get install -y network-manager-vpnc-gnome`

Step 3:  Then check your **VPN setting**, it works in Ubuntu20.04